# Using Django authentication completely interdependent

Tags: python, django

Can I use Django authentication completely interdependent from users. My use case is simple, I have a  form which once completed allows the person to access the API in that session. The API is tastypie and authentication is session based I think so I need a valid session.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, but that doesn't mean you need to have anything in database. You can write your own [session engine](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/#configuring-the-session-engine) and [authentication backend](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#module-django.contrib.auth.backends). The former needs to return a valid user object, but it doesn't need to be retrieved from anywhere specifically, you can craft it manually.